# NextJs, provided ref is not yet hydrated, probably because it's defined higher up the tree

Tags: next.js13

I was working on a nextjs13 project, suddenly got a warning of :

```
You have defined a target options but the provided ref is not yet hydrated, probably because it's defined higher up the tree. Try calling useScroll() in the same component as the ref, or setting its `layoutEffect: false` option.
```

I have checked all the refs but the warning still pops up.
This my [GitHub](https://github.com/Sahil-B07/portfolio)